# PNG | graphics | file size output of multiple pngs

Tags: css, graphics, png, sprite

I have six PNG files for my new website, each ~200KB. I want to output all six images into one single PNG to create a CSS sprite. But when I output the file, it is over 6MB! This also means I can't use tinypng to reduce the file.

I am using iDraw but have tried various other methods and get the same result every time.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I really do want to use a sprite.

Comment: Try pngcrush; it doesn't have a filesize limit.

Comment: How are you combining the six into one? If they are all the same size, 1x6, 2x3, 3x2 or 6x1? If not, how then? But I have to add, 200Kb for a *compressed* image is quite large. How large are the images in *pixels*, and do you need them at that size?